# Mini explosion of wires or lightbulb

Tags: electrical, wiring

I was putting up a hanging ceiling light. I connected all the wires, turned the light on and off, nothing happened. I got up to see what it's about. In the moment that I saw the brown wire somehow un-connected, a mini explosion happened with the wires. Do you know what it is about and did I do a lot of damage?
PS: Please don't jedne me, I'm just an overly enthusiastic college student

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box where this happened?

Comment: The only way we can help is if you provide us detailed information about your situation. Pictures of the inside of the ceiling box would be a good start.

Comment: Also *where* you are. Mention of a "brown" wire could locate you in the UK, for example.

Comment: It's possible that you just tripped a circuit breaker.

Comment: Tina, you probably just shorted the wires, *the power wire touched another or the metal box*,  and that tripped the breaker. The breaker is designed to trip so that "a lot of damage and injury can be avoided.  We need more info to be able to provide an informed answer.

Comment: I would guess that your "mini explosion" was a spark.